# GA custom dimension data not tracking

Tags: google-analytics

I have created the dimension, it's currently my only one so it has index 1. It has session level scope and is active.

I have also created a custom report to see any results I might get from it. All the report does is show the Session metric against my custom dimension. Nothing extra such as filters.

In my code (which until now was unmodified) I have added the following line **between** the 'create' and 'send' calls:

```
ga('set', 'dimension1', 'test');
```

Nothing is appearing in the report, or anywhere else when I use this dimension as a secondary dimension.

I have tried on a second GA property of mine and it also doesn't work there.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it takes 1-3 hrs for the dimension data to show in GA UI. But there are ways to check if the hit you sent contains the dimension or not.

1. On your browser, check the ga requests ( Like in chrome -> Inspect -> Network -> filter by `collect`). If you have included the dimension correctly, the pageview hit sent must contain **`cd1`** parameter (1 is the index of the dimension). If the hit contains the dimension and value, then wait for few hours and your report will show the data.
2. You can also use [Google Analytics Debigger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna) to check the requests sent to ga by your website page